# select2 optgroup ajax json fomat

Tags: json, ajax, laravel, jquery-select2

i want to group returned json data by `libelle` i end up with the following
script :

```
$('.membre').select2({
        placeholder: 'Select an item',
        ajax: {
          url: '/select2-autocomplete-ajax',
          dataType: 'json',
          delay: 250,
          data: function (params) {
            return {
              membre_id: params.term // search term

            };
          },
          processResults: function (data) {

            return {
              results:  $.map(data, function (item) {
                    return {

                        text: item.libelle,
                        children: [{
                        id: item.id,
                        text: item.nom +' '+ item.prenom
                        }]

                    }
                })

            };
          },
          cache: true
        }
});
```

Output :
[image]

is there any possibility to make the group work properly without repeating the `libelle` ?

JSON output :

```
[{"id":1,"libelle":"Laboratoire Arithm\u00e9tique calcul Scientifique et Applications","nom":"jhon","prenom":"M"},{"id":2,"libelle":"Laboratoire Arithm\u00e9tique calcul Scientifique et Applications","nom":"JHON","prenom":"jhon"}]
```

Comment: please provide 2 or 3 elements from the json output

Comment: Also, check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/49105479/5844171

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you're looking for something like this https://select2.org/data-sources/formats#grouped-data

```
// Add this somewhere before the ajax
var groupBy = function(xs, key) {
  return xs.reduce(function(rv, x) {
    (rv[x[key]] = rv[x[key]] || []).push(x);
    return rv;
  }, {});
};


processResults: function (data) {
   return {
      results:  $.map(data, function (item,key) {
         var children = [];
         for(var k in item){
             var childItem = item[k];
             childItem.text = item[k].nom +' '+ item[k].prenom;
             children.push(childItem);
         }
         return {
            text: key,
            children: children,
         }
    })       
 };
```

Comment: do you mean : processResults: function (data) {
            
            return {
              results:  $.map(groupBy(data,'libelle'), function (item,key) {
                    var children = item;
                    return {

                        text: key,
                        children: item.nom +' '+ item.prenom,
                        
                    }
                })
              
            };
          },

Comment: i'm getting only the optgroup data no childrens displayed

Comment: What does it log when you console.log item before the return statement?

Comment: (14) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0
:
{id: 1, nom: "jhon", prenom: "M", libelle: "Laboratoire Arithmétique calcul Scientifique et Applications 2016 - 2019 « FSO »"}

Comment: after the last answer i did change results:  $.map(data, function (item,key) { to results:  $.map(groupBy(data,'libelle'), function  (item,key) { and now it's working fine thank you  Sérgio Reis